# How to get the following dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Hello I have the following list with labels:

```
label=['0','0','1','0','1','2','4','3','3','3','0']
```

I have a corresponding list of elements:

```
elements=['element0', 'element1', 'element2', 'element3', 'element4', 'element5', 'element6', 'element7', 'element8', 'element9', 'element10']
```

Both have the same length:

```
print("length label:",len(label),"length elements",len(elements))
```

output:

```
length label: 11 length elements 11
```

I would like to construct a dictionary with the label as key and a list of all the elements that has the same label, this would be the desired output:

```
dict={'0':['element0', 'element1','element3','element10'],'1':[ 'element2','element4'],'2':['element7'],
      '3':['element7', 'element8', 'element9'],'4':['element6']}
```

I am trying to use "list comprehensions" as follows:

```
dict={}
for i in range(0,len(elements)):
    dict{i}=[#A list with all the elements that has the same label]
```

However I would like to appreciate support to achieve the desired dictionary, thanks for the support, the MCVE is the following:

```
from __future__ import print_function

label=['0','0','1','0','1','2','4','3','3','3','0']
elements=['element0', 'element1', 'element2', 'element3', 'element4', 'element5', 'element6', 'element7', 'element8', 'element9', 'element10']

print("length label:",len(label),"length elements",len(elements))
dict={}
```

Comment: Please don't use `dict` as a variable name. You destroy the function by the same name.

Comment: @dawg thanks for the suggestion I will change this in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setdefault` like so:

```
>>> result={}
>>> for k,v in zip(label,elements):
...    result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
... 
>>> result
{'2': ['element5'], '0': ['element0', 'element1', 'element3', 'element10'], '3': ['element7', 'element8', 'element9'], '4': ['element6'], '1': ['element2', 'element4']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> mydict = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i,j in zip(label, elements):
...   mydict[i].append(j)

>>> print mydict
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'1': ['element2', 'element4'], '0': ['element0', 'element1', 'element3', 'element10'], '3': ['element7', 'element8', 'element9'], '2': ['element5'], '4': ['element6']})
```

Since you wanted the keys to be sorted:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> out_dict = OrderedDict()
>>> for keys in sorted(mydict):
...   out_dict[keys] = mydict[keys]

>>> print out_dict
OrderedDict([('0', ['element0', 'element1', 'element3', 'element10']), ('1', ['element2', 'element4']), ('2', ['element5']), ('3', ['element7', 'element8', 'element9']), ('4', ['element6'])])
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate  the support, thanks for the atention